# Why does OSX Lion hang when my backup drive starts up?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I'm on Lion 10.7.2, I did a migration from Snow Leopard, and everytime I try to do something on my computer that requires some CPU - i.e. after effects scrubbing of the time line - the computer freezes/hangs for a moment. The time machine backup doesn't even have to start, the drive just spins up, I'm not sure what's going on here....

Comment: For what it's worth, I get timeouts all the time when my attached disk spins up. I just [told it not to power down anymore](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-can-i-increase-the-time-before-my-external-drive-powers-down).